# Prompting to run the program again: fixing if they put an invalid statement in

Tags: c++

Morning!

My question: I state in the program to enter Y for yes and N for no. If the user enters yes, no, or a random string, it will say that it's an invalid input and ask again. But say the user enters "yes yes yes", it will output the invalid statement three times. How could I resolve this?

I also need to do something about the boolean because it serves no purpose as I break the loop if they say n, but nevermind that.

Here's a fragment of my code:

```
bool done = true;
string ans;

try {
   coeff input = readCoeffs();
   results result = equSolver(input);
   outResults(input, result);

   while (done == true) {
      cout << "Would you like to run the program again (Y to run again, N to close)? ";
      cin >> ans;
         if (ans == "Y" || ans == "y") {
            coeff input = readCoeffs();
            results result = equSolver(input);
            outResults(input, result);
         }
         else if (ans == "N" || ans == "n") break;
         else cout << "Invalid input. \n";
   }
}

catch (const char* msg) {
   cerr << msg << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd advise removing your first question from this question,(we like there to be 1 question per question) and making your title more descriptive

Comment: Alright! I'll do that now.

Comment: Put in a `true` into the loop, the way you are going is normally only required in multithreaded applications (worker threads etc.)

Comment: and actually, it's early night here, you know ;)

Comment: Btw, you should probably initialize `done = false`, and then your loop condition is `while(!done)` which makes a lot more sense than what you have. That, or rename `done` to something like `runAgain`.

Comment: @SamIam I don't think there's anything wrong with asking two short questions related to the same snippet of code. I think this question was actually very well put, especially for a new user of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities that I came up with:

1. Use `getline(cin, ans)`
2. Set the limit to the amount of characters read as follows:

`char input[100];
cin.getline(input,100);`

Comment: Hopefully at least one of those worked? If so, accept my answer!

Comment: Of course! I used getline(cin, ans);

But when I do, it automatically goes through my if else statement, says that it's invalid, then lets me type in Y or N. Here's a screenshot: http://oi58.tinypic.com/9gg2g9.jpg

Comment: Maybe if you add an if statement like this it will keep from doing that: `if(!ans){ break; }`.  It's hard to say what the issue is at this point.

Comment: Also, see the answer below about setting `while(done == false)`.  This might be important.

Comment: Well, I cant do !ans because it's a string, but what I did was before getline, I did if (ans == "") {break;}, and indeed the loop did break. So what the loop is doing is getting the string from when it was first created, and using that (as an empty string), then running through again with the string cleared and asking for my input. So I need to somehow clear the string and ask for input right away. I tried ans.clear(); before the getline, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Indeed, all of the boolean variables are fixed up.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't initialize `string ans;` immediately before the `getline()`?  If you try it does it fix the problem?

Comment: I can do that, but still to no avail.

Comment: You said you already tried using `cin.ignore();` right after the `getline();`?  If not, try that.  See this link: http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html

Comment: Hm, that did the trick of getting rid of the blank invalid input, but now it completely ignores all input with getline. I tried an if (ans == "") cin.ignore(); but that's going to make stage 1 happen every time the loop runs (the string being empty). I'll take a look at the I/O tut

Comment: Yes, it seemed like that tutorial was talking about your issue precisely, so it might have something else you could try.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
while(done == false)
```

Done should be initialized to false, and in your loop, set done to true when they enter N or n.  It's somewhat a style question, but it's usually best to avoid breaks unless there's a REALLY good reason.

For your invalid input issue, you are using

```
cin >> ans;
```

This is broken by whitespace, so in put of "l m n o p" is going to make the program say "invalid input" twice, then exit.  Look into using getline if you want to process by line instead.

Comment: `done` starts with `true` here. WIth ==false the loop will never execute. The name of the variable is odd. It should be named `notDone` or have values flipped.. Be careful when reading someone other's code.

Comment: Yes.  It shouldn't start out "done" either.  I hoped that was obvious, but editing to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll definitely change the variables up. I didn't realize how confusing that could be. Could I instantiate that my "done" variable is true and break the loop instead of using break;?

Comment: You could change it to `bool notDone = true;`, `while(notDone)` if you want.  I'm not entirely sure what you meant to ask?

Comment: When I put the break; in after they type in 'n' it simply breaks the loop, to me it seems like the boolean didn't serve a purpose in the loop.

Comment: True, but breaks are usually something you want to avoid unless there's a good reason.  You could definitely do `while(1)` or `while(true)` instead of using a bool and keep the break.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are simple enough.

#### 1.

You can use `while(true)` and get rid of the `done` flag.  or instead of using `break;`, flip the `done` flag. (Btw, I think you either misnamed the variable, or you flipped the boolean values... it still works but semantically it makes no sense.)

#### 2.

`cin` only reads up to the next whitespace, which can be a space. If you want to read the whole line, you need to use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/). So instead of

```
cin >> ans;
```

use

```
getline(cin, ans);
```

EDIT: I fixed which `getline` is used. Should be correct now.

Comment: Hm, actually when I used getline it would automatically say invalid input, then ask again for my input. Here's a screenshot: http://oi58.tinypic.com/9gg2g9.jpg

Comment: I forgot to notify you!

Comment: @Auchindoun Strange. That sounds like you are simply getting a blank line to start with? Looking at the documentation again, it looks like `getline` _appends_ to whatever is already in the string, so maybe you need to call `ans.clear()` before `getline`. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Could I perhaps instantiate that ans is a string inside of getline, and rid of the first string ans; statement? Like so: getline(cin, string ans); ?